# Load usercontrol into tabcontrol

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to put two usercontrols into the tabcontrol, but only when I click on a button the usercontrol will load the data

```xml
<Button Click="Button_Click_1" />
<Button Click="Button_Click_2" />
<TabControl>
    <ItemsControl Name="tab1">
        <local:UserControl1 Loaded="UserControl1_Loaded"></local:UserControl1>
    </ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl Name="tab2">
         <local:UserControl1 Loaded="UserControl2_Loaded"></local:UserControl1>
    </ItemsControl>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: I tried to upload the data button (eg into the combobox) but without success,   Do add the code?

Answer (score 0):

```
private class  TabSource 
{
   private string dataForTab = string.empty; 
   public string DataForTab { get { return dataForTab; } } 
   public void GetRealData()
   {
      dataForTab = "Real Data";
      NotifyPropertyChanged("DataForTab");
   }
}


public Button_Click_2(...)
{
    MyTabSource.GetRealData();       
}
```

Comment: It does not work. The combobox is in usercontrol and the page does not know him

Comment: What is combobox binding to? Bind to an object that is empty by default. Then have the Button bind to an ICommand of that loads the object.

Comment: @Rhyous The original question did not have a combobox.  This was a just a simple example of how to update data based on an event.  String would be bound to something like  TextBlock.

Comment: @user1095549 Come on, apply yourself